# How to set a DroidWall custom script for allowing global access to the LAN via wifi?

Tags: networking, firewall

I'm trying to follow the second example at http://code.google.com/p/droidwall/wiki/CustomScripts :

```
# Allow all connections to the local network (192.168.0.XXX) on Wi-fi
$IPTABLES -A "droidwall-wifi" --destination "192.168.0.0/24" -j RETURN
```

I added this string into the custom script box and applied the rules, but apps which aren't whitelisted for access (I'm using just the whitelist mode) can't access the local network.

What am I doing wrong?